# Matcher find() a specific repeating pattern

Tags: java, regex

Here is my data :

```
'%%case.r_object_id%%' and  application_phase = '%%case.status%%'  and rp.quality =  '%%case.<reno_application_person>.<child>.quality%%
```

I want to get all the objects enclosed in double percent `%%`, we have 3.

Based on my implementation, matcher.find() finds the first `%%` and the last  `%%` in the string. So its just one loop. How can i adjust my regex or code to ensure i get 3 matches ?

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(%%[^\"\n]+%%)").matcher(results);

    while (matcher.find()) {
                try {
                    matcher.appendReplacement(stringbuffer, getReplacementStringValue(matcher.group().replaceAll("%", "")));
                } catch (DocumentGeneratorException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this regex `%%(.*?)%%`:

```
String regex = "%%(.*?)%%";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    //                               ^------note to get the group one
}
```

**Outputs**

```
case.r_object_id
case.status
case.<reno_application_person>.<child>.quality
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this approach works

Answer (score 1):

If you use a reluctant quantifier after your custom class, the parser should match at the next occurrence of the double `%%` rather than go through the entire string: `"(%%[^\"\n]+?%%)"`.

Note the question mark after the `+`.

Also remember to:

`matcher.appendTail(stringbuffer)`

... once you're done!

**Docs**

See the "quantifiers" sections of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).